# Leaking Bypass Valve

Tags: plumbing

I have a Culligan Gold series Gen 2 water softener. The bypass valve seeps around the bypass screw knob. Can the bypass valve be dissasembled and resealed? I assume a o-ring is worn out.

Comment: How about a picture so we can see what you see.

Comment: Have you scoured the web for an instruction manual? There are dozens of online parts retailers that will happily sell you replacement parts. You may be able to replace just an o-ring, you might have to replace the whole valve. You might find that building your own bypass out of a couple of valves and some tubing is cheaper than buying an official Culligan replacement part.

Comment: I have examined the culligan owners manual, which has a breakdown of everything but the bypass valve. I'm trying to find a way to attach a picture of the assembly. The bypass assembly is locked into control unit with pins versus fittings.